# iterate through matrix R

Tags: r, for-loop, matrix, iterator

I have "cbind"ed 2 matrices to make matrix "x" such that the 1st column of each line up together and the same for the second column pairs:

```
X1   Y1   X2   Y2    etc.   
val  val  val  val
val  val  val  val
val  val  val  val
```

In the actual created matrix there are many more columns than the above example.
I'm trying to iterate through the matrix with:

```
    for (i in 1:49){
       slope = atan((x[i+1,2]-x[i, 2])/(x[i+1,1]-x[i,1]))
    }
```

So as you can see I'm trying to get the slope from consecutive values descending down the first 2 columns. My problem is that I don't know how to make this function iterate over the entire matrix and do the same to every column pair.
Any tips?

Comment: for (i in 1:49) 49 is because there are 50 rows in each column

Answer (score 1):

The first step is to find the difference between each element by column. Then we apply the slope function. (For comparison of results, @latemail's example matrix was used).

```
diffs <- apply(x, 2, function(x) x[-1]-x[-length(x)])
atan(diffs[,c(F,T)]/diffs[,c(T,F)])
#             Y1       Y2
# [1,] 0.7853982 1.249046
# [2,] 1.1071487 1.325818
# [3,] 1.3258177 1.446441
# [4,] 1.4464413 1.508378
```

How about a one-liner solution which is a blend between the two answers : )

```
atan(diff(x)[,c(F,T)]/diff(x)[,c(T,F)])
```

**Data**

```
x <- cbind(X1=1:5,Y1=c(1,2,4,8,16),X2=1:5,Y2=c(1,4,8,16,32))
```

Comment: Wow thanks! However my matrix is called "x" so I changed "mat" to "x" can I get away with that? when I run the command it says Error: dim(x) must have a positive length

Comment: @Chris I don't have your data, it can be anything. The example I provided is there to show you that it works. Yes you can change the names.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid the looping and use some functional programming like `diff` and `paste`

```
x <- cbind(X1=1:5,Y1=c(1,2,4,8,16),X2=1:5,Y2=c(1,4,8,16,32))
x

#     X1 Y1 X2 Y2
#[1,]  1  1  1  1
#[2,]  2  2  2  4
#[3,]  3  4  3  8
#[4,]  4  8  4 16
#[5,]  5 16  5 32

dfx <- diff(x)
atan(dfx[,paste0("X",1:2)]) / dfx[,paste0("Y",1:2)]

#            X1       X2
#[1,] 0.7853982 1.249046
#[2,] 1.1071487 1.325818
#[3,] 1.3258177 1.446441
#[4,] 1.4464413 1.508378
```

Comment: wow that looks pretty good. but it returns:
                dfx <- diff(x)
                Error in r[i1] - r[-length(r):-(length(r) - lag + 1L)] : non-numeric argument to binary operator

Comment: @Chris - no, it doesn't. The code I have is reproducible and complete. Please try it in a fresh R session.